# Troubleshooting message-less OperationError when using SubtleCrypto

Tags: javascript, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to unwrap a key using SubtleCrypto.unwrapkey... my unwrap algorithm is:

```
{name: 'RSA-OAEP', hash: Object{name: 'SHA-1'}, modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: Uint8Array{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1}
```

while my unwrappedKeyAlgo is:

```
{ name: 'AES-CBC', altName: 'aes256-CBC',length: 256, usages: pri: ['decrypt', 'unwrapKey'], pub: ['encrypt', 'wrapKey'] }}
```

My call looks like this:

```
    return webcrypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
        'raw',
        // wrappedKey
        encSymmKey,
        // unwrappingKey
        keyPair.private,
        // unwrapAlgo
        keyAlg,
        // unwrappedKeyAlgo
        symmAlg,
        // extractable
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    )
```

I've been trying a few different things to no avail, and while for most of the day I am getting an OperationError without any message (i.e. error.message is ''), towards the end I started getting:

```
 0, 'OperationError', '192-bit AES keys are not supported'
```

even though there's no 192-bit key in sight as far as I can see.

Does anyone have any tips on how to debug/troubleshoot both message-less OperationError cases (it's just not much to go on with, really), and/or the latter. What is the go-to place (other than stack overflow) for questions on similar subjects?

Answer (score 0):

IE11 (judging by your errors) is broken in this regard. This has to be done as a two step procedure, first decrypting:

```
msCrypto.subtle.decrypt(keyAlg, keyPair.private, encSymmKey)
```

and then importing the result 'k':

```
msCrypto.subtle.importKey('raw', k, symmAlg, true, ['encrypt', 'decrypt'])
```

Hope that saves you some trouble ;-)